# Add new attribute to "ColumnSeries" tag in RadHtmlChart (Telerik)

Tags: c#, asp.net, telerik, radchart

I would like to know how to add custom attribute to the `ColumnSeries` attribute of `RadHtmlChart` control from Telerik?

I then want to access this attribute in code behind of asp.net page to set the `Value` but I don't to show the value of `CustomeAttribute` to `RadHtmlChart` on the asp.net Page.

```
<telerik:ColumnSeries CustomeAttribute=""></telerik:ColumnSeries>
```

Comment: This is not an `asp-classic` question, could you remove the asp-classic tag please?

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Server properties are strictly defined in the control's class and adding your own that the code will not recognize is likely to result in a server error.
If you need information on the client you can store it in hidden fields, hidden panels or inject a custom JavaScript object from the server via the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript() method.